# Does a Chern-Simons term break the $F \rightarrow \star F$ symmetry?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, chern-simons-theory, duality

When is the electro-magnetic duality $F \rightarrow \star F$ a symmetry of a theory? I know it holds for free Yang-Mills, but would for instance a Chern-Simons term break it or a coupling to matter? And is the duality a part of the Lorentz symmetry as they both mix electric and magnetic fields? So if a theory is Lorentz symmetric, is it also symmetric under the electro-magnetic duality?

Comment: What dimensions are you working in? How do you produce your C-S form? Have you written down the Duality transformation explicitly and Lorentz-transformed both sides? As it is, you are tossing words around expecting a revealing essay in return.

Comment: I am working in three dimensions with a $U(1)$ gauge group, therefore my Yang-Mills term looks like $F \wedge \star F$ and my chern-simons term is $F \wedge A$. To make my question as specific as possible; is the lagrangian $\frac{1}{e^2} F \wedge \star F + k \ F \wedge A$ still invariant under the electro-magnetic duality $F \rightarrow \star F$

Comment: How many indices does your $\star F$ have in 3 dimensions?

Comment: one, since $F$ is a two form and the hodge star maps it to 3-2 = 1 form.

Comment: Right ...so can you write that duality map explicitly in components in your question?

Comment: The transformation of the field strength in components is $\begin{bmatrix}
o & F^{0 1} & F^{0 2} \\
-F^{0 1} & 0 & F^{1 3} \\
-F^{0 2} & -F^{1 3} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} F^{1 3} \\ F^{0 2} \\ - F^{0 1} \end{bmatrix}$ but I do not know the corresponding transformation of the gauge potential. I think it might be ill-defined for it is the integral of $dA \rightarrow \star dA$. That's is why I think a chern-simons term will break the symmetry. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: 3 spacelike indices? not 2? Why don't you write down what you think is the maxwell action and inspect it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79459/discussion-between-graphite-and-cosmas-zachos).